# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null in action_login.php

Tags: php, database, mysqli, mysqli-multi-query

when i log on to my user account it shows these warning:-

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in
>   /hermes/bosnaweb24a/b1323/ipg.techbitercom1/duracomexteriors/admin/action/action_login.php
>   on line 12 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   /hermes/bosnaweb24a/b1323/ipg.techbitercom1/duracomexteriors/admin/action/action_login.php:12)
>   in
>   /hermes/bosnaweb24a/b1323/ipg.techbitercom1/duracomexteriors/admin/action/action_login.php
>   on line

i'm attaching my action_login.php code

```
<?php

    require_once("../../db_connection/dbConnection.php");
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST["ok"])){
        $username=$_POST["username"];
        $password =$_POST["password"];

            if(mysqli_query($con, "select * from tbl_admin_log where user_name='$username' or email='$username' and password='$password'")){
                $_SESSION["login"] = $username;
                $_SESSION["passw"] = $password;
                while($ln = mysqli_fetch_array($log, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    $_SESSION["log_type"] = $ln["type"];
                }
                header("location:../admin.php");
            }
            else{
                header("location:../index.php?failed=Invalid Username or Password!");
            } 
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: session_start always need to be very first line of the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Comment: $log is not defined anywhere,

Comment: again showing the same results

Comment: You need to define the result from the query with `if ($log = mysqli_query(.....)) {` - then you should group the conditions in the query, or you will experience undesired results. Lastly, you should use prepared statements with placeholders in the query to prevent sql injection.

Comment: this worked for me, thanks for your valuable reference

Answer (score -1):

Put `session_start()` above your `require_once()` statement.

Answer (score -1):

Use something like this and see if it works

```
session_start();    
require_once("../../db_connection/dbConnection.php");

if(isset($_POST["ok"])){
  $username=$_POST["username"];
  $password =$_POST["password"];

  $checkLogin = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_admin_log WHERE (user_name='$username' OR email='$username') AND password='$password'") or die(mysqli_error($con));      
  if(mysqli_num_rows($checkLogin)>0){
    $_SESSION["login"] = $username;
    $_SESSION["passw"] = $password;
    $checkLoginRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkLogin);
    $_SESSION["log_type"] = $checkLoginRow["type"];
    header("location:../admin.php");
  }else{
    header("location:../index.php?failed=Invalid Username or Password!");
  } 
}
```

Comment: One question abhi, do you have username in both username and email columns in database table?

Answer (score -1):

**1st :** Move your `session_start()` on very top of page

**2nd :** you need to group the or condition using  paranthesis like this `(user_name='$username' or email='$username')`

**3rd :**  First check the  query is success or not then count the result using this if condition  `if(($log) && mysqli_num_rows($log)>0){ }`

```
"select * from tbl_admin_log where (user_name='$username' or email='$username') and password='$password'"
```

**PHP :**

```
$log = mysqli_query($con, "select * from tbl_admin_log where (user_name='$username' or email='$username')  and password='$password'") or die(mysqli_error($con));

 if(($log) && mysqli_num_rows($log)>0){

        $_SESSION["login"] = $username;
        $_SESSION["passw"] = $password;
        $ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($log, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION["log_type"] = $ln["type"];

        header("location:../admin.php");
}
else{

    header("location:../index.php?failed=Invalid Username or Password!");
}
```